# Interweave groups in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that I want "intereaved" row-wise by groups.

For example, this DataFrame:

| Group | Score |
| --- | --- |
| A | 10 |
| A | 9 |
| A | 8 |
| B | 7 |
| B | 6 |
| B | 5 |

The desired result would be grabbing the first of A, and the first of B, then the second of A, then the second of B, etc.

| Group | Score |
| --- | --- |
| A | 10 |
| B | 7 |
| A | 9 |
| B | 6 |
| A | 8 |
| B | 5 |

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.3/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumcount.html) of each `Group` as a sorting key :

```
out = df.sort_values("Group", key=lambda _: df.groupby("Group").cumcount())
```

Or better, as suggested by @mozway, you can use one of these variants:

```
out = df.sort_values(by="Group", key=lambda s: s.groupby(s).cumcount())
```

---

```
out = df.iloc[np.argsort(df.groupby("Group").cumcount())]
```

Output :

```
print(out)

  Group  Score
0     A     10
3     B      7
1     A      9
4     B      6
2     A      8
5     B      5
```

Comment: Better reference the series itself (this makes it work in a pipeline): `df.sort_values(by='Group', key=lambda s: s.groupby(s).cumcount())`. Alternatively: `df.iloc[np.argsort(df.groupby('Group').cumcount())]`

Comment: Thank you mozway ;) I updated the answer to include your suggestions.

Comment: `df.sort_values` approach remains faster against `df.iloc`: `408 µs` - `554 µs` respectively (on the current input sample)

Comment: But the first one might need reindexing the DataFrame, while iloc always works

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

Another possible, which calculates the number of elements by group, `n`, and then, by reshaping and flattening the index of the dataframe with a convenient order (order `F`), gets the proper index to reindex (with `iloc`) and obtain the wanted output:

```
n = len(df) // df['Group'].nunique()
df.iloc[df.index.values.reshape(-1, n).flatten(order='F')]
```

---

**Solution 2**

Yet another possible solution, which is based on `list comprehension`. This solution may not be as efficient as the previous one, because there is a `groupby`:

```
g = df.groupby('Group')
df.iloc[[index for y in zip(*[x.index for _, x in g]) for index in y]]
```

---

**Output**

```
  Group  Score
0     A     10
3     B      7
1     A      9
4     B      6
2     A      8
5     B      5
```